# Why do the .bbl-file and BibTeX database not contain the same information?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing, bbl

I have a question regarding using references. It was all working the way it was supposed to work until yesterday night. I am writing my research proposal and I am citing a lot of papers. At some point, LaTeX decided that it was enough. I have been looking through my files and concluded that my `.bbl`-file contains less information than my BibTeX file. How can this happen and how am I supposed to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "LaTeX decided that it was enough" mean? You could really help us out by showing the contents of one bib entry that's afflicted by the work stoppage as well as the associated bbl entry and by stating which bibliography style you use.

Comment: We are all out of crystal balls, please elaborate. Exactly what is missing? Is bibtex giving you any errors you have overlooked

Comment: BibTeX can handle arbitrarily many references so it is mostly likely something that you have done. Try and distill it down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that you can give us the details. Most likely in the course of doing this you will find the problem but if not you will give people on TeX.SX the information that they need to solve it for you.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

That is the whole point of what bibtex does, you could have just one bibtex file for every reference you ever make in every document, and each entry could have every field that you may ever conceivably want to print alongside the reference.

bibtex then takes the aux file from the latex run, which tells it which citations are needed, and the bibliography style to use, and the bibliography style specifies which fields to use from each entry.

So, not printing every entry in the bib file and not printing every field in an entry are the expected behaviours so there is nothing to solve.

In special cases (eg debugging a bib file) where you want to print all the entries even if they are not cited in the document you can use `\nocite{*}`